# Is there an equivalent to "Android Localization Files Editor" for android-studio?

Tags: android, localization, android-studio

In Eclipse there is a localization strings editor that displays a table with all the available XML files. (Eclipse's Sequoya or previously MOTODEV Studio):

[image: Android Localization Files Editor screenshot]

Is there and alternative for Android Studio (or for Intellij in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. We'll look into this later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this in the Studio yet, but you can a platform like [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) to manage your strings and localized files and work with translators..

(discl: I'm the founder of Transifex)